# Error accessing files in home directory?

Tags: command-line

[image]
 If I want to open downloads in terminal like cd downloads, it says no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Windows, Ubuntu is case sensitive. So it should be `cd Downloads`. If you start a terminal with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or via the Dashboard your starting point is your home directory `/home/<your_userID>`. `ls` gives you the files and directories located here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be cd /home/YourName/Downloads/